# bash script, how do I launch firefox

Tags: bash, symfony

I wish to write a bash script such that it launches Symfony built-in Web Server, hence Firefox. The following simple minded script fails because - I am not sure how to describe it by the correct jargon - the shell gets busy by the first task. I guess it is simple, but I am newbie on this. Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/mySymfonyProj  
php bin/console server:run localhost:8080
/usr/bin/firefox  http://localhost:8080
```

Comment: @ hnefati. Yes, perfect! Thanks. Do you happen to know a basic but well written tutorial on `&`, `wait`, and related background infos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(moved comment to answer in order to "resolve" the question).

Add an `&` after the 4th line of the script to run that process in the background - the shell will launch that process, and move onto the next line (but will wait for the 5th line's command to finish).

At the end of the script, you may want to call `wait` to wait for the server to terminate, if that's desired.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/mySymfonyProj  
php bin/console server:run localhost:8080 &
/usr/bin/firefox  http://localhost:8080
wait
```

For more information on job control, look at [this source](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html). It doesn't cover everything useful, but it covers a fair amount.

I'd mention that `$!` returns the PID of the process just executed, so you can keep track of the PIDs of various background tasks then use `wait` to delay until they've returned - that's often useful.